Accented characters in MsgBox and Project Object in Office 2021 not showing
All language settings (Windows 10, Office 2021) are set to French.
MsgBox does not display the accents.
In the VB Editor:

At run time:

In the Project Object list:

Where is the setting if existing?
This apparently comes from the VBA Editor since if I build the same code on another PC with Office 2016, the MsgBox is well displayed on both PCs.
If the code comes from the PC that faces the issue, the MsgBox is wrongly displayed on both PCs.
Is there a way to set a language in the VBE?

Also the Général is weird in Object drop-down.

Indeed, and also when I copy a macro file from another PC, when the names of the macros contain accents, again they are showing with this question mark in a black losange.

Does this answer your question? How do I display a messagebox with unicode characters in VBA?

Eddy, no, as there is no Unicode invoved in this text. This is only ASCII typed on the keyboard.

Check your localisation in Windows settings. Mine is Danish and displays nicely your messagebox:


Gustav, what do you mean by Localisation. The Windows parameters / Localisation which shows a map on which one have to "Define a localisation by defaut" ?
Does not change the MsgBox display (after re-editing it in the VBE). Neither the "Allow applications to access your location" activated option.

I found 1 equivalent issue with Access on Microsoft site (in French) but no solution.
https://answers.microsoft.com/fr-fr/msoffice/forum/all/impossible-dafficher-correctement-les/18bf70ec-3e2b-429c-aa27-9c97194b6ff3

It is not about coordinates. It is the language settings of Windows.

All Windows and Office language settngs were fine. This is of course the first thing I verified.

OK. Then I have no other suggestions apart from the repair/reinstall which I can see you did.

I completely re-installed Windowd 10 from the Dell Computer, removed pre-installed Microsoft 365 (Office) and all Microsoft Office 365 in 4 or 5 languages, re-installed Office 2021 and eventually the problem is fixed !
I strongly suspect these Microsoft 365 things to be the cause of the problem.
